# Twitter4J Access token explanation?

Tags: java, oauth, twitter, twitter4j

How does getting the AccessToken work with Twitter4J?

When I send the user to the Authorization URL and the callback URL comes back with values `oauth_token` & `oauth_verifier` how do I then use these values to create an Accesstoken? I've tried `new AccessToken(token,verifier)` and `getOAuthAccessToken(token,verifier)` but it always seems to throw back errors.

How do I correctly use there two values to create the AccessToken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RequestToken reqToken = (RequestToken) session.getAttribute(REQUEST_TOKEN);
session.removeAttribute(REQUEST_TOKEN);

if (!reqToken.getToken().equals(oauthToken)) {
        throw new TwitterException("Wrong oauth_token");
}
AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(reqToken);
```

You need to store the `RequestToken` object in the session before redirecting.

Comment: But the request token is simply sent back with the callback.. no?

Comment: should this be sent before the uri intent, or after callback?

Comment: the request token is generated and sent before invoking the initial url